# Angular2+ How to create a blank page (no HTML/CSS completely) with OK string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm absolutely sure this question wasn't been asked before.
So I'm developing a website application, which has payment integrated.
Everything works fine.. but the problem is, that when the payment is complete i need to provide a callback for the payment provider with.. 
"OK" string.

There problem is, that they are reading only first two chars of the page in search of "OK".

The question: How to do this with angular5?

Comment: One option could be a static page in assets, and just redirect/pass that?

Comment: Good point, but the thing is, that i have to check data in callback url. And all this script which is responsible for data checking may be displayed